# Why do $this->db->affected_rows() returns 0?

Tags: php, mariadb, codeigniter-3

Following function is written in codeigniter 3 for deleting user:

```
    public function deleteUser($id) {

        $this->db->trans_start();

        $this->db->where('usma_user_id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('ec_usma_usermain');          

        $this->db->trans_complete();            

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {

            $transResult = array(
                            'response' => 'Operation failed!',
                            'status' => TRUE
                            );

        } else if ($this->db->trans_status() === TRUE) {

            if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ) {

                $transResult = array(
                                'response' => 'Operation executed successfully!',
                                'status' => TRUE
                                );

            } else {

                $transResult = array(
                                'response' => 'Unexpected error! Contact admin.',
                                'status' => FALSE
                            );

            }
        }

        return $transResult;

    }
```

In above function even when there is a row and it is deleted response returned is

> Unexpected error! Contact admin

Which means value returned by

```
    echo $this->db->affected_rows();
```

is 0 (zero). So I checked (echoed) the output of

```
    echo $this->db->affected_rows();
```

before

```
    echo $this->db->trans_complete();
```

is executed, it returned no. of deleted rows (in my case 1 row) and if same line of code is written after

```
    echo $this->db->trans_complete();
```

it returns 0. Why is it so?

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/3098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `$this->db->affected_rows()` returns the number of rows affected by last statement. Here last statement is  `$this->db->trans_complete()` by which number of affected row is `0`.

Comment: What value is returned by commit transaction or queries?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the note on this page: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html

*"Note: In MySQL “DELETE FROM TABLE” returns 0 affected rows. The database class has a small hack that allows it to return the correct number of affected rows. By default this hack is enabled but it can be turned off in the database driver file."*

As long as this hack is enabled (and it sounds like it is from your question), then a workaround would be to simply store the `affected_rows` after the query executes and before you end the transaction. It would look something like this:

```
public function deleteUser($id) {

$this->db->trans_start();

$this->db->where('usma_user_id', $id);
$this->db->delete('ec_usma_usermain');          

//store the affected_row value here
$affectedRows=$this->db->affected_rows();

$this->db->trans_complete();            

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {

    $transResult = array(
                    'response' => 'Operation failed!',
                    'status' => TRUE
                    );

} else if ($this->db->trans_status() === TRUE) {

    //recall the stored value here
    if($affectedRows > 0 ) {

        $transResult = array(
                        'response' => 'Operation executed successfully!',
                        'status' => TRUE
                        );

    } else {

        $transResult = array(
                        'response' => 'Unexpected error! Contact admin.',
                        'status' => FALSE
                    );

    }
}

return $transResult;
```

}

Comment: I followed that link before asking question and didn't got "hack" thing. And also question is why line of code works when it is written before transaction is completed or outputs correct value. Thank you.